# Linear algebra - vectors and spaces, what does it mean for a set of vectors to be a basis/linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I just know how to find out whether the set is a basis for space V, I understand the concept span, but I don't understand what it means for a set of vector to be a basis, and why these 2 conditions determine whether it is or not(linearly independent & span)

Answer (score 1):

The basis is the least number of vectors that spann the space V. 
eg, in 3 dim , if you have 3 vectors you can spann 3d but only if they are linearly independent ( each vector "add something new ) or in other words none of them can be written as scalar times the other . 
The vectors (1,0,0 ) ( 0 1 0 ) and ( 0 0 1) are a basis for 3D why ? 
Because they are linearly independent , and they spann 3D .

if on the other hand you had (1 0 0 )  , ( 0  1  0) and ( 0  , 2 , 0 ) they cannot be a basis in 3d.

Answer (score 1):

A basis is a set (mind you, a set that is minimal in size) that spans some vector space.

Now what does this mean? You have probably intuitively thought or understood the concept of a basis. For example, I think you would agree that the vector $1$ spans the set of all integers. (Using the operation of addition and subtraction only). Really? Is it just $1$? Why not the set $\{1, 10\}$? Well it's not a basis anymore and this should be intuitively true.

What about the $xy$ plane, that is $(x, y)$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. I claim that $(1, 0), (0, 1)$ spans this and it seems pretty obvious that we can't do it with more or less vectors.

And that's what a basis is, it is a set that is proven (I have not shown how to prove it, but from your question, you seem to say that you already know the process) to be minimal in size and spans the entire set. That is, we cannot find another set of smaller cardinality than our basis, and still have that set span the vector space.

The concept of linear dependency is a consequence of the basis being minimal. If we have some vectors in the set that is not linearly independent, we can remove it and we would still get the same span since it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Question:I don't understand what it means for a set of vector to be a basis, and why these 2 conditions determine whether it is or not(linearly independent & span)

My attempt at a simple answer:

These results follow from the Replacement Theorem.

1) A Basis $\beta$  can be used to represent any vector in your vector space---> It is a generating set or spanning set.
2) A basis $\beta$ is a *minimal*  spanning set-->  Linear Independence of vectors in $\beta$